# How to use AWS cognito with cognito groups to restrict access to API endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have been looking to find out how it would be possible to use AWS cognito groups to restrict access to API endpoints based on cognito group policies.

1. I have created the ID pool with user pool.
2. Added a cognito group policy then associated it to an IAM policy.
3. In the policy it gives access to the API gateway endpoint ARN
4. There is an authorizer which uses the AWS cognito pool

The issue is that if a cognito user has not been added to the group in cognito then they should not have access to the API gateway endpoint. Currently it still allows access when the group has not been assigned to that user.

Here is my policy, which is set in the cognito group.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-1:0:xxxx/*/*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-sync:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-sync:eu-west-1:x:identitypool/eu-west-2:0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thankyou

Comment: did you get any answer for this?